# Refactoring: Merging two dictionaries, but ignoring None values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, refactoring

I need a bit of Python refactoring advice.

I have a list of dict objects (`new_monitors`), which can be empty. When there are new monitors, however, I want to add a bunch of fields to those monitors.

For each monitor, I would like to append all `not None` fields from the `DogDump.HIDE_FIELDS` dict:

```
if new_monitors:
  for monitor in new_monitors:
    for key, value in DogDump.HIDE_FIELDS.items():
      if value:
        monitor[key] = value
```

Note: This snippet below worked very well, but it included all of the None fields. I do not want the None fields!

```
if new_monitors:
  for monitor in new_monitors:
    monitor.update(DogDump.HIDE_FIELDS)
```

How can I refactor this snippet that looks more *pythonic*, but still maintain good readability?

Comment: Maybe this question might be better suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: You might be right, I didn't know this feature existed. Is there a way to move this question, or should I just re-create it in the CodeReview section? I saw that there is a `refactoring` tag, so I went with it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which is really the most "pythonic" way of handling your need to filter `DogDump.HIDE_FIELDS` dict before adding the relevant key / value pairs to your `monitor` dict. One way would be to perform the "filtering" with dict comprehension.

Also, I would think that you could "filter" your `DogDump.HIDE_FIELDS` dict before your loop rather than repeating this operation for each loop iteration (unless there are other operations taking place that mutate `DogDump.HIDE_FIELDS` while you are iterating).

Example of "filtering" with dict comprehension (`dump` refers to your `DogDump.HIDE_FIELDS` dict):

```
monitor = {'key': 'value'}
dump = {'a': 1, 'b': None}

dump_filtered = {k:v for (k,v) in dump.items() if v}
monitor.update(dump_filtered)
print(monitor)
# OUTPUT
# {'key': 'value', 'a': 1}
```

Comment: In the end I decided to just remove `None` values from the dict and used `monitor.update(DogDump.HIDE_FIELDS)`